# Reconciling 2 nodeJS socketIO solutions

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I need to modify an existing CylonJS_socketIO solution so that it accommodates another default socketIO implementation. Having trouble, so would appreciate any feedback. I'm guessing it has something to do with the transports object since I'm using flashsocket client on the front end https://github.com/simb/FlashSocket.IO, but I'm not a node ninja. I don't think I need or require express.

This is the default bare bones socketIO implementation

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server,{transports:['flashsocket', 'websocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling']});

var port = Number(8080);
server.listen(port);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

var temp;
 var _this = this;

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('connection '+socket)
        socket.on("data",function(d){console.log('data from flash: ',d);});
        socket.emit("message","wtfwtwftwftwf hello from server");
        socket.on('disconnect', function (socket) {
            console.log("disconnect");
        });

        console.log('_this ='+_this);
        _this.socket=socket;

});
```

And this is the CylonJS-socketIO code I have to modify by incorporating the above somehow

```
'use strict';
var Cylon = require('cylon');

Cylon.robot({
    name: 'tesla',
    connections: {
        edison: { adaptor: 'intel-iot' }
    },
    events: ['range_sent', 'turned_on', 'turned_off'],

    commands: function() {
        return {
            range_on: this.rangeOn,
            toggle: this.toggle
        };
    },

    devices: {
        maxbotix: { driver: 'maxbotix', pin: '0' },
        led: { driver: 'led', pin: 13 }
    },

    work: function(my) {
        var range = 0;
        every((0.1).seconds(), function() {
            range = my.maxbotix.range();
            console.log('Maxbotix range: ', range);
            this.rangeOn(range);
        }.bind(this));
    },

    rangeOn: function(data) {
        console.log('rangeOn in Server');
        //this.led.turnOn();
        this.emit('range_sent', { data: data });
    },

    toggle: function() {
        this.led.toggle();
        if (this.led.isOn()) {
            this.emit('turned_on', { data: 'pass some data to the listener' });
        } else {
            this.emit('turned_off', { data: 'pass some data to the listener' });
        }
    }
});

Cylon.api(
    'socketio',
    {
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: '3000'
 });

Cylon.start();
```

Comment: One might ask why `flashsocket` is your preferred transport?

Comment: AIR client front end although a regular websocket would work as well